# Collapsable signatures in Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-signature

Most of my colleagues have really long email signatures (with three logos, contact information etc.)
When I'm writing a reply to their emails the signature takes so much screen space that I can't see my reply and their original mail on one screen.

Is there any way to modify the signature so readers will be able to collapse it to avoid scrolling? I've asked them to reduce the size the signature without success but I think I could persuade them to modify their signature slightly if it's required.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail signatures are plain text with some very few formatting options. You can add color, change fonts (limited), text size (more limited), or add an image. You can't add arbitrary HTML.

However, when writing replies, Gmail should be smart enough to recognize a signature and get it out of your way. (A screen shot of what you're seeing would be helpful in your question.)

My best suggestion is for your colleagues to add the long-standard `--` (that's two dashes followed by a space) in a line by itself above the signature. This harkens back to the Usenet days (I remember people with multi-page signatures) and is a signal to the client (if it cares) that "everything that follows is a signature and not part of the message". Gmail uses that signal.

But, again, I'm a heavy Gmail user and I've not experienced what you describe. It'd be great if you could add a screen shot. (Block out any personal information, of course.)